# Cannot add to family tree using Jquery function

Tags: jquery, tree

I'm creating a small website where you can create a family tree by adding children or gran children. I'm using [CSS3 family tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) but the problem I have is when a child or gran child is added they are not being added to the correct li when a button is clicked. I may also want to remove the child or gran child when a button is clicked this may require keeping a count, though I'd prefer to get the adding completed first and then move on to removing.
Any suggestions woulds be very much appreciated.
Thanks

```
 <ul id="navlist">            
        <li>
            <button type="button"  id="addChild"> Add Child</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button"  id="addSib"> Add Sibling</button>
        </li>            
        <li>
            <button type="button" id="removeChild"> Remove Child</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" id="removeSib"> Remove Sibling</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Family Tree Layout

```
<div id="content-body">
        <div class="tree">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="p">
                        <div class="parent"></div>                              

                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="li2">
                            <a href="#" class="c">
                                <div class="child"></div>                      

                            </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="li3">
                                        <a href="#" class="s">
                                            <div class="sib"></div>                                                                                            
                                        </a>
                                     </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The functions

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addChild").click(function(){
        var row = $('a').parent('.li2');
        var c = $("<a href='#' class='c'><div class='child'></div></a>");

        $('c').append(row);
        c.appendTo(row);
    });


    $("#addSib").click(function(){
        var row = $('a').parent('.li3')
        var a = $("<a href='#' class='s'><div class='sib'></div></a>");

        $('s').append(row);
        a.appendTo(row);

    });

});
```

Comment: buttons should only appear when a node is selected by an event, then you have a target

Comment: Can I not add a child or gran child on button click rather than selecting a node first

Comment: Sure but you would have to drag it to where it would need to go. On a big tree that wouldn't be very user friendly

Comment: Alternative would be a selection method for target in your form

Comment: A selection method would keep track of what is being added or deleted?

Comment: I'm not to confident with functions in jquery is there any examples I could use.